# How to restore words from embedded words in keras?

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, keras, embedding

I am now using `Embedding` layer for my NLP problem. My model predicts one word as an answer. So the final output's shape is `(None, vocab_size)`.

My question is how to restore original word from embedded vectors without new `Dense` layer? For example, below `x` is `(None, 4, 8) = (None, sequence_length, embedding_dim)`. Then, I want to extract most possible `i-th word` from actual `x`.

```
...
inp = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype='int32') # ex) ['who','are','you','?']
x = Embedding(output_dim=embd_dim,
              input_dim=vocab_size, 
              input_length=max_length, 
              name='my_emb')(inp)
answer = restore_word_from_embedded_data(x) # what i want to do. ex) 'tom'
# No, i want to extract a word without new Dense layer
# answer = Dense(vocab_size)(answer) from current Embedding weights, 'my_emb'.
...
```

Here is brief summary of Input and Embedding.

```
input_6 (InputLayer)         (None, 4(seq_length))                          
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_9 (Embedding)      (None, 4(seq_length), 8(embed_dim))
```

Comment: Learn another set of parameters that maps the embeddings to your layer. The typical encoder-decoder architecture should be words->lookup->embeddings->lookup->words. Without another set of parameters to map from the embedings to your output lookup table, you only have high level abstract vectors that cannot be interpreted as they are.

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec and https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq

Comment: @alvas Is the second `lookup` usually `Dense` layer? Like `answer = Dense(vocab_size)(embeddings)`

Comment: Yes it normally is a dense layer.

Comment: BTW, you should tag the question with `keras` and remove the `machine-learning` to get more attention from canonical `keras` experts (myself is not one) ;P